# How can I redirect with Url rewrite e.g. from https://www.contoso.com to another server?

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

How can I redirect with url rewrite e.g. from https://www.contoso.com to another server e.g. to https://www.testpage.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use iis url rewrite for redirection, and use this rule:

```
<rule name="test">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.contoso.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.testpage.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I do not want to forward from http to https but from https to https

Comment: The rule in this answer also apply to HTTPS to HTTPS.

Comment: But the rule does not work